# Rewrite a url and rerun the server block

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to rewrite a url like the following but without sending a 301 to the client (change the url and then restart processing of the server block with the new url).

```
rewrite ^/a/b/$ /a/c/d permanent;
```

I would normally just reorder the lines but it's a really convoluted config and also really large.

Answer (score 0):

`permanent` always means redirect, replace it with `last`

check the `last` flag in the [reference page](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#rewrite)